# Jest mocked import for each function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, i18next

I'm having problems mocking the module 'i18next' (v23.4.1) in a jest (v29.6.4) test for a react (v18.2.0) app.
The thing is, I have to mock both the 'exists' and 't' functions.
Here is the code that works:

```
import { function } from 'module'

jest.mock('i18next', () => {
  const lib = jest.requireActual('i18next');
  lib.exists = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => true);
  lib.t = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => "TRANSLATED");
  return lib
}) 


define ('tests', () => {
  it('test 1', () => {
    // Testing
  })
  ...
})
```

What i need is, in some tests, change the values of exists and/or t, but i can't find the right way.
I've tried with spies, changing the function of the mock dinamically, with doMocks, etc